# Android 4.4 crash signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) StringObject::utfLength() const

Tags: android, crash, native, android-4.4-kitkat, segmentation-fault

Facing this issue. Unable to reproduce but getting these crashes in google play console after our latest release. Please help. Only effecting Android 4.4. More than 1700 reports this week.

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)
StringObject::utfLength() const

backtrace:
  native: pc 000000000005596c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (StringObject::utfLength() const+17)
  native: pc 000000000004b6e5  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  native: pc 0000000000017341  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
  native: pc 00000000000174e7  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
  native: pc 000000000001dd8c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
  native: pc 000000000004e253  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
  native: pc 00000000000271a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  native: pc 000000000002e150  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
  native: pc 000000000002b7fc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
  native: pc 0000000000060843  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+338)
  native: pc 0000000000060867  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
  native: pc 0000000000055547  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  native: pc 000000000000d280  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  native: pc 000000000000d41c  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? Thanks

Comment: not yet :(.. you also facing it?

Comment: Yes, I updated my app for other reasons and the error mostly disappeared on its own. Still there but occuring rarely. I think I updated the sdk and redownloaded the 4.4 one at some point, but not sure if that's related.

Comment: We couldnt find a solution for this. So reverted the version and released apk  for versions <20 sdk and new apk supporting versions >20